# How to exclude weekends between two dates using Moment.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I am trying to exclude weekends in my JavaScript code. I use moment.js and having difficulty choosing the right variable for 'days'.

So far I have thought that I need to exclude day 6 (saturday) and day 0 (sunday) by changing the weekday variable to count from day 1 to day 5 only. But not sure how it changes.

My jsfiddle is shown here: [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Xt2e6/)

**HTML**:

```
<div id="myContent">
<input type="radio" value="types" class="syncTypes" name="syncTypes"> <td><label for="xshipping.xshipping1">Free Shipping: (<span id="fsv1" value="5">5</span> to <span id="fsv2" value="10">10</span> working days)</label> </td><br>
    <div id="contacts" style="display:none;border:1px #666 solid;padding:3px;top:15px;position:relative;margin-bottom:25px;">     
    Contacts
</div>
<input type="radio" value="groups" class="syncTypes" name="syncTypes"> <td><label for="xshipping.xshipping2">Express Shipping: (<span id="esv1" value="3">3</span> to <span id="esv2" value="4">4</span> working days)</label> </td>    
<div id="groups" style="display:none;border:1px #666 solid;padding:3px;top:15px;position:relative">     
    Groups
</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
var a = 5; //Free shipping between a
var b = 10;//and b
var c = 3;//Express shipping between c
var d = 4;//and d    
var now = moment();    
var f = "Your item will be delivered between " + now.add("days",a).format("Do MMMM") + " and " + now.add("days",b).format("Do MMMM");
var g = "Your item will be delivered between " + now.add("days".c).format("Do MMMM") + " and " + now.add("days",d).format("Do MMMM");

var h = document.getElementById('contacts');
h.innerHTML = g

var i = document.getElementById('groups');
i.innerHTML = f

$(function() {
    $types = $('.syncTypes');
    $contacts = $('#contacts');
    $groups = $('#groups');
    $types.change(function() {
        $this = $(this).val();
        if ($this == "types") {
            $groups.slideUp(300);
            $contacts.delay(200).slideDown(300);
        }
        else if ($this == "groups") {
            $contacts.slideUp(300);
            $groups.delay(200).slideDown(300);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If there is no support for working days only, how about finding first monday last Sunday and do weeks*7 - weeks*2 and add preceding workday(s) and trailing workdays

Comment: a, b, c, d, f, g, h, i... That'll make readable and maintainable code.

Comment: Is there a way to use an if statement since the delivery times are fixed. For freeShipping: if todaysDate = Monday -> firstDate = todaysDate + 7days) lastDate = todaysDate + 14days. But this would have do be done for each day of the week i assume?

Answer (score 73):

Here you go!

```
function addWeekdays(date, days) {
  date = moment(date); // use a clone

  while (days > 0) {
    date = date.add(1, 'days');
    // decrease "days" only if it's a weekday.
    if (date.isoWeekday() !== 6 && date.isoWeekday() !== 7) {
      days -= 1;
    }
  }
  return date;
}
```

You call it like this

```
var date = addWeekdays(moment(), 5);
```

I used `.isoWeekday` instead of `.weekday` because it doesn't depend on the locale (`.weekday(0)` can be either Monday or Sunday).

Don't subtract weekdays, i.e `addWeekdays(moment(), -3)` otherwise this simple function will loop forever!

Updated JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Xt2e6/39/ (using different momentjs cdn)

Comment: Nice. I now use a version of this. But I've amended with: `var inc = days / Math.abs(days);` updated the while conditional to `days != 0` and changed the occurrences of `1` to `inc`. This way I can 'add' a negative number of workdays.

Comment: The problem with this is that it uses a loop so it will not scale

Comment: Smart use of a while loop

Comment: Nice snippet, thanks ! But the `date = date.add(1, 'days');` could be just `date.add(1, 'days');` as Moment instances are mutable

Answer (score 23):

Those iteration looped solutions would not fit my needs.
They were too slow for large numbers.
So I made my own version:

https://github.com/leonardosantos/momentjs-business

Hope you find it useful.

Comment: So ... how do I add two moment object and only get Business days using this?

Comment: @ppumkin: There is also [moment-business-days](https://github.com/kalmecak/moment-business-days), but it does not have a diff function.

Comment: @BillyTom [moment-business-days](https://github.com/kalmecak/moment-business-days) now has businessDiff

Answer (score 12):

https://github.com/andruhon/moment-weekday-calc plugin for momentJS might be helpful for similar tasks

It does not solves the exact problem, but it is able to calculate specific weekdays in the range.

Usage:

```
moment().isoWeekdayCalc({  
  rangeStart: '1 Apr 2015',  
  rangeEnd: '31 Mar 2016',  
  weekdays: [1,2,3,4,5], //weekdays Mon to Fri
  exclusions: ['6 Apr 2015','7 Apr 2015']  //public holidays
}) //returns 260 (260 workdays excluding two public holidays)
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want a pure JavaScript version (not relying on Moment.js) try this...

```
function addWeekdays(date, days) {
    date.setDate(date.getDate());
    var counter = 0;
        if(days > 0 ){
            while (counter < days) {
                date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1 ); // Add a day to get the date tomorrow
                var check = date.getDay(); // turns the date into a number (0 to 6)
                    if (check == 0 || check == 6) {
                        // Do nothing it's the weekend (0=Sun & 6=Sat)
                    }
                    else{
                        counter++;  // It's a weekday so increase the counter
                    }
            }
        }
    return date;
}
```

You call it like this...

```
var date = addWeekdays(new Date(), 3);
```

This function checks each next day to see if it falls on a Saturday (day 6) or Sunday (day 0). If true, the counter is not increased yet the date is increased.
This script is fine for small date increments like a month or less.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest adding a function to the moment prototype.

Something like this maybe? (untested)

```
    nextWeekday : function () {
        var day = this.clone(this);
        day = day.add('days', 1);
        while(day.weekday() == 0 || day.weekday() == 6){
          day = day.add("days", 1);              
        }
        return day;
    },
    nthWeekday : function (n) {
        var day = this.clone(this);
        for (var i=0;i<n;i++) {
          day = day.nextWeekday();
        }
        return day;
    },
```

And when you're done and written some tests, send in a pull request for bonus points.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a version of @acorio's code sample which is performant (using @Isantos's optimisation) and can deal with negative numbers use this:

```
moment.fn.addWorkdays = function (days) {
  // Getting negative / positive increment
  var increment = days / Math.abs(days);
  // Looping weeks for each full 5 workdays
  var date = this.clone().add(Math.floor(Math.abs(days) / 5) * 7 * increment, 'days');
  // Account for starting on Saturdays and Sundays
  if(date.isoWeekday() === 6) { date.add(-increment, 'days'); }
  else if(date.isoWeekday() === 7) { date.add(-2 * increment, 'days'); }
  // Adding / removing remaining days in a short loop, jumping over weekends
  var remaining = days % 5;
  while(remaining != 0) {
    date.add(increment, 'days');
    if(date.isoWeekday() !== 6 && date.isoWeekday() !== 7)
      remaining -= increment;
  }
  return date;
};
```

See Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dain/5xrr79h0/

Edit: now fixed issue adding 5 days to a day initially on a weekend

Comment: Hey @dain I didn't understand this `var increment = days / Math.abs(days);` 
It will be always 1, right?

Comment: @csaiki no, in case `days` is negative (ie you want to decrement days) then it'll be -1

Comment: makes sense! Thanks =)

Comment: There is a problem with this code. If today is saturday and I add 5 days then I get next saturday instead of friday. Same for sunday. How do I go around this?

Comment: @RotimiBest well done for spotting the error after 5 years  just fixed it and added some comments in the code

Comment: @dain or anyone else using this, just a heads up, the `while` gets stuck in an infinite loop if the `days` param isn't an integer, so I used `Math.ceil` on the `days` to avoid that issue.  It works great otherwise though . Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

d1 and d2 are moment dates passed as an argument to `calculateBusinessDays`

```
calculateBusinessDays(d1, d2) {
    const days = d2.diff(d1, "days") + 1;
    let newDay: any = d1.toDate(),
    workingDays: number = 0,
    sundays: number = 0,
    saturdays: number = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < days; i++) {
        const day = newDay.getDay();
        newDay = d1.add(1, "days").toDate();
        const isWeekend = ((day % 6) === 0);
        if (!isWeekend) {
            workingDays++;
        } 
        else {
            if (day === 6) saturdays++;
            if (day === 0) sundays++;
        }
    }
        console.log("Total Days:", days, "workingDays", workingDays, "saturdays", saturdays, "sundays", sundays);
    return workingDays;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this question was posted long ago, but in case somebody bump on this, here is optimized solution using moment.js:

```
function getBusinessDays(startDate, endDate){
  var startDateMoment = moment(startDate);
  var endDateMoment = moment(endDate)
  var days = Math.round(startDateMoment.diff(endDateMoment, 'days') - startDateMoment .diff(endDateMoment, 'days') / 7 * 2);
  if (endDateMoment.day() === 6) {
    days--;
  }
  if (startDateMoment.day() === 7) {
    days--;
  }
  return days;
}
```

Comment: This is not good. if startDate is MON and endDate is 3 days later (THU), the result is the same than starting on FRI, and endDate 3 days later (MON).

4 days may or may not include the week-end.

Comment: This doesn't calculate it correctly. I got negative days even though the start date was earlier than the end date.

Answer (score 0):

```
const calcBusinessDays = (d1, d2) => {
    // Calc all days used including last day ( the +1 )
    const days = d2.diff(d1, 'days') + 1;

    console.log('Days:', days);

    // how many full weekends occured in this time span
    const weekends = Math.floor( days / 7 );

    console.log('Full Weekends:', weekends);

    // Subtract all the weekend days
    let businessDays = days - ( weekends * 2);

    // Special case for weeks less than 7
    if( weekends === 0 ){
    const cur = d1.clone();
    for( let i =0; i < days; i++ ){
        if( cur.day() === 0 || cur.day() === 6 ){
        businessDays--;
        }
        cur.add(1, 'days')
    }
    } else {
    // If the last day is a saturday we need to account for it
    if (d2.day() === 6 ) {
        console.log('Extra weekend day (Saturday)');
        businessDays--;
    }
    // If the first day is a sunday we need to account for it
    if (d1.day() === 0) {
        console.log('Extra weekend day (Sunday)');
        businessDays--;
    }
    }

    console.log('Business days:', businessDays);
    return businessDays;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without looping between all dates in between.

```
// get nb of weekend days
var startDateMonday = startDate.clone().startOf('isoWeek');
var endDateMonday = endDate.clone().startOf('isoWeek');

var nbWeekEndDays = 2 * endDateMonday.diff(startDateMonday, 'days') / 7;
var isoDayStart = startDate.isoWeekday();
if (isoDayStart > 5) // starts during the weekend
{
    nbWeekEndDays -= (8 - isoDayStart);
}
var isoDayEnd = endDate.isoWeekday();
if (isoDayEnd > 5) // ends during the weekend
{
    nbWeekEndDays += (8 - isoDayEnd);
}

// if we want to also exlcude holidays
var startOfStartDate = startDate.clone().startOf('day');
var nbHolidays = holidays.filter(h => {
    return h.isSameOrAfter(startOfStartDate) && h.isSameOrBefore(endDate);
}).length;

var duration = moment.duration(endDate.diff(startDate));
duration = duration.subtract({ days: nbWeekEndDays + nbHolidays });

var nbWorkingDays = Math.floor(duration.asDays()); // get only nb of complete days
```

Answer (score 0):

I am iterating from start date to end date and only counting days which are weekdays.

```
const calculateBusinessDays = (start_date, end_date) => {
        const d1 = start_date.clone();
        let num_days = 0;
        while(end_date.diff(d1.add(1, 'days')) > 0) {
                if ([0, 6].includes(d1.day())) {
                        // Don't count the days
                } else {
                        num_days++;
                }
        }
        return num_days;
}
```