# javascript count backwards 23 week days from current day for stock tracking

Tags: javascript, date

I am working on an application to get historical stock data from yahoo finance csv api.  I am having trouble creating a script that will get the current day and count back 23 weekdays (not counting weekends or holidays).  The idea is that it will plug the two dates in at yahoo, get the  historical data and then create a moving average.  I am unsure how to do this using the date function though.

Comment: function addWeekdays(date, days) {
  date = moment(date); // use a clone
  while (days > 0) {
    date = date.add(1, 'days');
    // decrease "days" only if it's a weekday.
    if (date.isoWeekday() !== 6 && date.isoWeekday() !== 7) {
      days -= 1;
    }
  }
  return date;
}/

Comment: this could be start point, it is actually adding days, you need subtract and tweak as per your need.

Comment: and yes, I didnt do the down votes.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/) library, if you are able to provide that to your page.  You could use it to do something like this:

```
var today = moment();
var pastDate = today.subtract('days', 23);
// then do something with those two variables...
```

if you need them in a certain format before you pass them along, just call `.format` on them

```
getHistoricalData(today.format('YYYYMMDD'), pastDate.format('YYYYMMDD'));
```

Comment: Just realized you were asking for weekdays, so [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20788411/how-to-exclude-weekends-between-two-dates-using-moment-js) may be relevant