# Get the number of Sundays of a month using moment.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, momentjs

I need the total number of `sunday's` and `saturday's` of a month. using `moment.js` library. Can anyone help me. Thanks

Comment: maybe this thread can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20788411/how-to-exclude-weekends-between-two-dates-using-moment-js

Comment: there is no inbuilt function, you have to find it programatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a solution using moment.js:

```
function getAmountOfWeekDaysInMonth(date, weekday){
    date.date(1);
    var dif = (7 + (weekday - date.weekday()))%7+1;
    console.log("weekday: "+ weekday +", FirstOfMonth: "+ date.weekday() +", dif: "+dif);
    return Math.floor((date.daysInMonth()-dif) / 7)+1;
}
```

The argument `date` has to be any date in the month you want analyse.

working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6k0jhzt6/1/)

NOTE: sunday is 0 and saturday 6