# Moment.js, Get next [weekday]

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Trying to get second coming Thursday (e.g.) using `moment.js`. **Not** this Thursday. The next one. The date in 2 Thursdays.

I have tried

`moment().add(1, 'week').day(4)`

which just fetches Thursday of the next week  (only works if current weekday is before Thursday)

Any ideas?

Comment: have you looked at the `.weekday()` property?

Comment: @Jhecht I have, what about it?

Comment: Why doesn't weekday work for what you need?

Comment: possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31476817/momentjs-next-business-day

Comment: @andrepaulo No man, next business day is easy. I'm trying to get the second instance of the weekday

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not understanding. Are you trying to get the result of `Monday` from your code above?

Comment: see this -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/39614998/5452965 if it helps you. Good luck

Comment: Are you _always_ trying to get the next thursday, regardless of what day it is?

Comment: Yes actually `weekday` works with a number greater than 7 to define the following week

Comment: yes I am aware. Has your issue been resolved?

Comment: If today is Thursday, should it give Thursday next week or in two weeks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"which just fetches Thursday of the next week (only works if current weekday is before Thursday)"

It's happening because .add(1, 'week') just adds 7 days and gets you the next week date and you are fetching 4th day of that week. 
Below code will work for your case perfectly.

```
if(moment().weekday() < 4)
 moment().add(1, 'week').day(4);
else
 moment().add(2, 'week').day(4);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about using moment.js, but in plain js next Thursday is given by:

```
currentDate + (11 - d.getDay() % 7)
```

For the following Thursday, just add 7 days. Presumably if the current day is Thursday, want the Thursday in two weeks so:

```js
var d = new Date();
console.log(d.toString());

// Shift to next Thursday
d.setDate(d.getDate() + ((11 - d.getDay()) % 7 || 7) + 7)
console.log(d.toString())
```

Or encapsulated in a function with some tests:

```js
function nextThursdayWeek(d) {
  d = d || new Date();
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + ((11 - d.getDay()) % 7 || 7) + 7);
  return d;
}

// Test data
[new Date(2017,2,6),  // Mon  6 Mar 2017
 new Date(2017,2,7),  // Tue  7 Mar 2017
 new Date(2017,2,8),  // Wed  8 Mar 2017
 new Date(2017,2,9),  // Thu  9 Mar 2017
 new Date(2017,2,10), // Fri 10 Mar 2017
 new Date(2017,2,11), // Sat 11 Mar 2017
 new Date(2017,2,12), // Sun 12 Mar 2017
 new Date()           // Today
].forEach(function (date) {
  console.log(date.toString() + ' -> ' + nextThursdayWeek(date).toString());
});
```