# Return Multiple Dates for Script on Page

Tags: javascript, date, web, getelementbyid, recurring

I am using the following script to return a date for a web page, however when using this script twice on a page only one date is returned (even when using different IDs). Should I be using an array for the startDate?

```
<script>
let startDate = "1 January 2020";
let startDateObj = new Date(startDate);
let recurringDay = 14;
let today = new Date();
var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
let totalDays = Math.floor((today-startDateObj)/(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
let daysLeftToRecur = (recurringDay - totalDays%recurringDay) || recurringDay;
let nextDate = new Date(new Date().getTime()+(daysLeftToRecur * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
document.getElementById("displaydate").innerHTML = days[nextDate.getDay()] + " " + nextDate.getDate() + " " + months[nextDate.getMonth()] + " " + nextDate.getFullYear();
</script>
```

Comment: Date will remain same for 24 hours. Time will differ. You are not printing the time.

Comment: Correct. I have two different "startDates" and two different "ID"s and I need to include them all into this script.

Comment: create a function.

Comment: I am attempting the following but it is still only returning one value:
let startDate = ["1 January 2020", "2 January 2020"];
let startDateObj = new Date(startDate[0, 1]);

Comment: https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-return-multiple-values/

Comment: Using the built–in parser for an unsupported format is a bad idea, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results) Adding days by adding time is also a bad idea, see [*How can I add 1 day to current date?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989382/how-can-i-add-1-day-to-current-date/9989458#9989458)

Comment: Hi @RobG, apologies I am only a beginner. I like the response you gave on the [Get next weekday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42612865/moment-js-get-next-weekday/42618434) thread. Could this work from a set start date eg. start date of 1 January 2020, and then displaying the next upcoming Thursday?