# Momentjs , How to skip sunday?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I have a condition where i have to send start and end date to a child component from parent component.

In simple, i will send a start date and end date to the child component.
The end date will be added to the start date (can be 3, 5, 7).
i.e if start date is 2016-01-01 (and variable to add is 3) the end date is 2016-01-03.

However, i need to take in account another condition where i have to skip Sunday.

Lets say  if 2016-01-02 is a sunday then the end date should be 2016-01-04.

The start date is initalized in getInitialState()

```
getInitialState(){
    variable_to_add:5,
    start_date: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
}
componentDidMount(){
this.setState({end_date:moment().add(Number(variable_to_add),'day').format("YYYY-MM-DD")
}
render(){
return <CallChild start_date={this.state.start_date} end_date={this.end_date}
    },
```

Any suggesetions to accomplish or improve the code above will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Which version do you use? http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Pure Javascript with hints found in another page of Stack overflow [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20788411/how-to-exclude-weekends-between-two-dates-using-moment-js).

```
formatDate:function(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

    return [year, month, day].join('-');
},
addWeekdays:function(date, days) {
    var days = days-2;
    date.setDate(date.getDate()+2);
    var counter = 0;
        if(days > 0 ){
            while (counter < days) {
                date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1 ); // Add a day to get the date tomorrow
                var check = date.getDay(); // turns the date into a number (0 to 6)
                    if (check == 0) {
                        // Do nothing it's the weekend (0=Sun & 6=Sat)
                    }
                    else{
                        counter++;  // It's a weekday so increase the counter
                    }
            }
        }
    return this.formatDate(date);
},
```

My getInitailState looks like this:

```
    getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        date_from: moment().isoWeekday(1).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
        no_of_items : 7,
        start_date: moment().add(2,'day').format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
        value:0,
    };
},
```

And my Render function looks like:

```
render(){
return <DayMenu weekday={(item.weekday).toString()} color={this.getRandomColor()} dataItem={dataItem} start_date={this.state.start_date} end_date={this.addWeekdays(new Date(this.state.start_date),this.state.no_of_items)}/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create function like this for calculating needed date:

```
function addDaysWithoutSundays(date, daysToAdd) {
 var tempEndDate = moment(date).add(daysToAdd, "day"),
     countSundaysBetweenDates = function (startDate, endDate) {          
         var daysDiff = endDate.diff(startDate, 'days');
         return Math.floor((startDate.day() + daysDiff)/ 7 );
     },
   countSundays = countSundaysBetweenDates(date, tempEndDate);      
   return moment(date).add(daysToAdd - countSundays, 'days');
}
```

You could try it here  [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/FLhpq/3725/)  (You could find the result in console)