# Javascript multiple work hours calculate from date to now

Tags: javascript

I need a javascript like this one

```js
    // Calculate days since 7st May 2016
    var initialDate = new Date(2016, 5, 7);
    var now = Date.now();
    var difference = now - initialDate;
    var millisecondsPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    var daysSince = Math.floor(difference / millisecondsPerDay);

    // Write result to HTML
    document.getElementById('days_since').innerHTML = daysSince;
```

```html
<div id="days_since"></div>
```

but I would like to display hours and my work is eg. monday-friday from 10am to 6pm and every saturday from 11am to 3pm.

Any advice?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how stating work hours and getting the difference between two dates is related here. Do you mean you only want to include those hours in the calculation of the date?

Comment: Check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20788411/how-to-exclude-weekends-between-two-dates-using-moment-js)

Comment: Not sure what you mean with your work hours - can you elaborate? How do you want to adjust the calc according to that? Getting the hours is easy but not sure what you mean with that

Comment: I mean I don't want to calculate every day since the date. I would like to calculate only those hours that I mentioned and display it in a div

Answer (score 0):

Hi please refer this http://jsfiddle.net/yentup/fKA9X/1/

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    var calcNewYear = setInterval(function(){
        date_future = new Date(new Date().getFullYear() +1, 0, 1);
        date_now = new Date();

        seconds = Math.floor((date_future - (date_now))/1000);
        minutes = Math.floor(seconds/60);
        hours = Math.floor(minutes/60);
        days = Math.floor(hours/24);

        hours = hours-(days*24);
        minutes = minutes-(days*24*60)-(hours*60);
        seconds = seconds-(days*24*60*60)-(hours*60*60)-(minutes*60);

        $("#time").text("Time until new year:\nDays: " + days + " Hours: " + hours + " Minutes: " + minutes + " Seconds: " + seconds);
    },1000);
});
```

and **HTML**

```
<div id="time"></div>
```