# Subtract days considering weekends

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, momentjs, weekend

I have a 4 dropdowns that are populated by dates, for example

```
["23rd December 2016","26th December 2016","27th December 2016","28th December 2016", "29th December 2016"]
```

In this scenario, I wish to avoid weekends.

The value of each respective dropdown is as follows

```
- 23rd December 2016
- 26th December 2016
- 27th December 2016
- 28th December 2016
```

The aim is that if I change the value of the first date from the 23rd ("A Friday") to 26th("A Monday"), the other 3 dates will shift one day to the following values;

```
- 26th December 2016
- 27th December 2016
- 28th December 2016
- 29th December 2016
```

This works fine with the following code

```
addWeekdays: function (date, days) {
        date = moment(date); // use a clone
        while (days > 0) {
            date = date.add(1, 'days');
            // decrease "days" only if it's a weekday.
            if (date.isoWeekday() !== 6 && date.isoWeekday() !== 7) {
                days -= 1;
            }
        }
return date;
}
```

The value of each dropdown loops through this function, `date` is the date value of the dropdown and `days` is the number of days difference between the initial date and the new date.

The problem I am having is that if I then try to shift from the 26th back to the 23rd I am unsure how to recreate it so I get the following;

```
- 23rd December 2016
- 26th December 2016
- 27th December 2016
- 28th December 2016
```

**Basically it's a way to subtract the difference in days exuding weekends, so if the difference in days is 2, I would like to go from Monday to previous Thursday and not to Saturday.**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20788411/how-to-exclude-weekends-between-two-dates-using-moment-js

Comment: @Rajesh That is the thread where I got my function into how to add days excluding weekends but I am still unsure as to how to subtract days excluding weekends

Comment: @gus27 Due to the `days` coming back as `-4` the while loop will not fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a separate `subtractWeekdays` function but you'd end up reusing most of the code. The major difference is the `1` in `date.add` and the while loop skipping when days is negative. We can fix this with a couple minor changes:

1. Use a pseudo-constant (I named it `dayConst` for simplicity of example) that will be positive or negative depending on context, instead of a hardcoded `1`, when calling `date.add`
2. Use a conditional to check if `days` is negative and if so, modify `dayConst` to reflect that, and make days positive, so the while loop runs in either case.

---

```
function addWeekdays (date, days) {
  // make a 'pseudo-constant' to represent the # used when adding/subtracting days
  var dayConst = 1;
  date = moment(date); // use a clone

  // add functionality for subtraction here
  if (days < 0) {
    dayConst = -1;
    days = -days;
  }

  while (days > 0) {
    // and then dayConst will be -1 if days is negative.
    date = date.add(dayConst, 'days');

    // decrease "days" only if it's a weekday.
    if (date.isoWeekday() !== 6 && date.isoWeekday() !== 7) {
      days -= 1;
    }
  }
  return date;
}

// How I tested them (It's Wednesday Nov 23 here and now, so 3 days +/-        
// is Monday Nov 28 and last Friday Nov 18, respectively)
console.log(addWeekdays(new Date(), 3).format("YYYY MM DD dddd"));
console.log(addWeekdays(new Date(), -3).format("YYYY MM DD dddd"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over number of days to `add/subtract` and then skip increment or `iterator` if its weekend.

```js
function addDaysWithoutWeekends(days, date) {
  var d = date || moment();
  var retDate = moment(d);
  var ittr = (days / Math.abs(days));
  while (days !== 0) {
    retDate.add(ittr, 'days');
    if (!isWeekend(retDate)) {
      days += (ittr * -1);
    }
  }
  return retDate;
}

function print(d) {
  console.log(d.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
}

function isWeekend(date) {
  return date.day() % 6 == 0;
}

// Add days
print(addDaysWithoutWeekends(10))

// Subtract days
print(addDaysWithoutWeekends(-10))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm getting stuck in an endless loop when I try this

Comment: Can you share your case? Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: @mcclosa did you copy `isWeekend`?