# How to exclude weekends between to dates to get total day count, and can federal holidays be excluded?

Tags: javascript

I am adding code to an adobe form using Java script, which the code below works to count days but need weekends excluded. How do I code this using my code below exactly? Also, is it possible to exclude federal holidays?:

All kinds of samples using other sample variables, but I cannot translate those sample variable to match with my initial code.

```py
var dd = this.getField("Text41").value;
var rd = this.getField("Text42").value;

var d1 = util.scand("mm/dd/yy", dd);
var d2 = util.scand("mm/dd/yy", rd);

var diff = (d2.valueOf() - d1.valueOf()) / 1000;

event.value = Math.round((diff / 60 / 60) / 24);
```

Displays count of total days between dates and displays 0 when `end date` is not provided.

Comment: you can get your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20788411/how-to-exclude-weekends-between-two-dates-using-moment-js/20948347

Comment: I did not find the answer there